# Apply nls() function to multiple subsets

Tags: r, nls

I need to run a non-linear least squares regression on an entire data set, and then repeat the regression on several subsets of that data set. I can do this for a single subset; for example (where y is a generic logistic equation, and x is a vector from 1 to 20):

```
example = nls(x ~ y, subset = c(2:20))
```

but I want to do this for 3:20, 4:20, 5:20, etc. I tried a for loop:

```
datasubsets <- sapply(2:19, seq, to = 20)
for (i in 1:19){
    example[i] = nls(x ~ y, subset = datasubsets[i])
}
```

but I receive "Error in xj[i] : invalid subscript type 'list'". I would very much like to avoid having to copy and paste nls() 20 times. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Did you try `datasubsets[[i]]`?

Comment: Maybe I'm asleep, but doesn't `sapply(2:19,function(jj) nls(x~y,subset=jj:20))`  do it for you?

Comment: That's a good thought. I've tried that, and currently the R console has hung up attempting the calculation. It's still churning... What do you mean by jj?

Comment: My problem was with my own script for y, so this works great now!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This does the job: `sapply(2:19,function(jj) nls(x~y,subset=jj:20))`.

Comment: Glad it worked for you.  Please click the checkmark on this answer so the question is tagged as answered.